# Path Matching for Journeys Using XY Coordinates

Tags: python, r, geometry, distance, similarity

I am trying to find some suggestions on ways or algorithms to determine path similarity. An illustration of 3 paths using made up data is given below. The title should be finding similar paths instead of calculating distance.

[image: Finding Similar Paths]

As you can see in the figure that there are two bus routes and one user journey. The original data will contain latitude/longitude coordinates. The journeys could be polylines/polygons/more complex shapes with or without intersections. I want to ask a few things:

1. Can frechet distance be used to find similarity between paths instead of between different points of a path or trajectory?
2. Do a path and trajectory mean the same thing?
3. Can we use frechet distance for polylines, polygonal curves and other shapes e.g., polylines with curves?
4. Can frechet distance handle intersections like present in the figure?
5. Are there other better methods of calculating path similarity?

The goal is to find a similar path within a given threshold of a user journey. let's say if there is/are route within 25 meters of the user path, then find how similar that route is to the user journey.

Any other suggestions/literature/recommendations/thoughts will be welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: 1 yes, 2 yes, 3 yes, 4 yes, 5 possible, but Frechet distance makes sense to me based on what i just read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distance. Note that for the original definition you need a monotously rising variable (time) to compare paths. If you don't have that (which I assume based on your description), you'd need to use the `weak Frechet distance`.

Comment: This is a theoretic problem and not yet presented in a form that is suitable for coding. Should be migrated.

Comment: Interesting question. It is well presented; I wish 25% of SO questions are as good as this. I'm upvoting it but also voting to close as it is not suited for this forum.